# как создать dbus шину в linux?

Tags: linux, c

у меня вопрос, у меня приложение требует root прав, так как работает с сетевыми пакетами. Если запустить без root прав, то приложение создает dbus нужные шины. Но если запустить с правами root, то ничего не создает. пробовал менять шину с session на system, всё равно не видно созданной шины. что делать?
уже получилось создать, но это не работает, только шина видна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
есть конфиг `com.xverizex.watcher.conf`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
    <policy user="root">
        <allow own="com.xverizex.watcher"/>
        <allow send_destination="com.xverizex.watcher" 
            send_interface="com.xverizex.watcher"/>
    </policy>
    <policy context="default">
        <allow send_destination="com.xverizex.watcher" 
            send_interface="com.xverizex.watcher"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

сам `skeleton` выглядит так.

```
<node name="/com/xverizex/watcher">
    <interface name="com.xverizex.watcher">
        <annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.Name" value="scanner" />

        <signal name="Clear"/>
    </interface>
</node>
```

я его с помощью `gdbus-codegen` делаю из него `skeleton`. так вот. если запустить без прав root и на сессионной шине, то интерфейс с сигналом видно, если запустить с root на системной шине, то видно только own шину, а интерфейса не видно.

Comment: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-run-session.1.html

Comment: что именно значит «это не работает»?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я дополнил описание.

Comment: @xverizex, понятно, что другому пользователю (в том числе root'у) на сессионную шину подключиться (без хаков) не удастся... а вот что на системную не пускает — странно... в подключении к шине ни где не налажал? точно на системную пытаешься подключиться? `g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export()` ошибок не возвращает? какую-нить странную конфигурацию polkit'а не делал? ну и на крайняк: не рассматривал вариант вместо работы от root'а просто дать приложению какой-нить подходящий мандат?

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну я делал в `polkit` что-то, типа `action` прописывал, но так и не понял, правильно ли сделал и нужно ли это делать для сигнала. а мандат я не знаю как дать, или ты имеешь ввиду suid bit? `skeleton` возвращает 1, то есть `TRUE`. тут всё нормально. то есть если сессионная, то всё нормально, если system, то видимо где-то не разрешил. вот как сделать? )

Comment: @Fat-Zer блин.  я же создаю с помощью `g_object`. и `own` создается в функции `startup`. а `export` создается в `dbus_register` методе `g_object`. хотя это даже не `g_object`, а `g_application`. да, я ошибся. это `g_application`. здесь есть метод `dbus_register`. вот его `connection` я и передаю в `export`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer я решил посмотреть в документации что там написано в `dbus-register`, и там написано что-то про сессионную, видимо она не учитывает system шину. `invoked locally during registration, if the application is using its D-Bus backend. You can use this to export extra objects on the bus, that need to exist before the application tries to own the bus name. The function is passed the GDBusConnection to to session bus, and the object path that GApplication will use to export is D-Bus API. If this function returns TRUE, registration will proceed; otherwise registration will abort. Since: 2.34`

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё, сработало. сделал по старинке. с помощью `introspection_data = g_dbus_node_info_new_for_xml (introspection_xml, NULL);`. спасибо за наводящие вопросы, они привели меня к нужным знаниям.

Comment: @xverizex, про мандаты: я имел в виду `setcap cap_net_raw <bin_file>` (подразумевая, что root нужен для работы с сырыми сокетами). Так можно дать бинарнику специальные права, но запускать его от простого пользователя; именно так от простого пользователя запускается, например, системный `ping`; см. подробности в `man 7 capabilities`

Comment: @Fat-Zer ага, спасибо, что-то помню об этом, но почти не использовал, так что даже забыл об этом, потому что даже в wireshark уже этого не делаю, а просто устанавливаю в группу `usermod -aG wireshark user` и всё.

Comment: @xverizex, если что wireshark точно также через мандаты работает: мандаты выданы dumpcap'у, но право на его запуск есть только у пользователей в группе `wireshark`...